# I'd like to create a SAS macro variable based on the value of 2 other macro variables

Tags: sas

I have 2 macro variables &k and &N.

I'd like to create a third macro variable &G
If &k is 1 I'd like &G to be &N
otherwise I'd like &G to be &k

many thanks

Comment: In concept, macro variable names are not preceded by `&`.  Names are just SAS valid names (start with _A-Z, and followed by up to 31 _A-Z0-9).  The ampersand `&` before a macro variable tells the system to substitute &<variable> with the value of <variable> (in other words, resolve the macro variable).  Advanced coders might perceive 'the &G macro variable blah blah blah' to mean the 'the macro variable, whose name is the value of the G macro variable, blah blah blah'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
%if &K = 1 %then %do;
   %let G = &N;
%end;
%else %do;
   %let G = &K;
%end;
```

Comment: wow that seems to work !! you're a star, Rohit, that has solved me a load of time, in fact I'm not sure I'd have ever worked it out. many thanks and stay safe

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `IFN` function within a `%SYSFUNC` wrapper to do simple conditional logic like this in a single line. The nice thing about `IFN` is it can also handle missing/empty more easily than having three IF/THEN/ELSE.

```
%let G = %sysfunc(ifn(&k=1, &N, &K));
```

Comment: thank you, Reeze, I will try this to - this is really improving my SAS skills :)